# show text after pressing button in android

Tags: android, button

I'm new to android, now i want to press a button then display text on the screen. here's my code:

**xml**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="sendMessages"
    android:text="Button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/buttonText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" 
    android:text="hello" />
```

**main activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

       .......
    }

    public void sendMessages(View view) {
        TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.buttonText);
          welcome.setText("button clicked");

    }
}
```

but when i run this on a simulator, after pressing the button, the application will report

```
fortunately, First Android App has stopped
```

does anyone know what's wrong with my program?

```
04-18 00:56:20.147: D/AndroidRuntime(1280): Shutting down VM
04-18 00:56:20.147: W/dalvikvm(1280): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
04-18 00:56:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1280): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-18 00:56:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1280): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
04-18 00:56:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     at     android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591)
04-18 00:56:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     at     android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
04-18 00:56:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
04-18 00:56:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-18 00:56:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-18 00:56:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-18 00:56:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-18 00:56:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 00:56:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-18 00:56:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-18 00:56:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-18 00:56:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-18 00:56:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1280): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-18 00:56:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 00:56:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-18 00:56:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
04-18 00:56:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     ... 11 more
04-18 00:56:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1280): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
04-18 00:56:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     at com.example.firstandroidapp.MainActivity.sendMessages(MainActivity.java:110)
04-18 00:56:20.177: E/AndroidRuntime(1280):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: post full error `LogCat`. Does this `Button` exists in the activity layout?

Comment: @Hamid Shatu  I've added the logcat output, the button does show up in the layout, but once pressed, the app will crash :(

Comment: @user2810081 clean and build your project

Comment: @Raghunandan I tried, but still crash

Comment: clean project and run and if it doesn't work then please put crash log

Comment: @user2810081 Please, post full xml layout and `sendMessages()` method code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do button and TextView exist in the activity layout?
Do you call *setContentView(Layout)* in onCreate?
Are you working with ADT?

If you are working with ADT you can create a new activity and
a new xml layout, so call setContentView(R.layout.YourLayout)
in onCreate

YourLayout.xml has to contains button and TextView

Comment: i did all of these, but when examining the xml i found that there's also a id name buttonText, i changed to another id and problem solved! Thanks!